# Swift getting array of Item objects using Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift

I just started programming in Swift, and am attempting to get back some of the results from my API, but as I understand it, I cannot simply return from the function, as it is async. I am using Alamofire and SwiftyJSON.

```
 func getItems(completionHandler: @escaping ([Item], Error?) -> ()) {
        getData(url: API.getUrl, completionHandler: completionHandler)
    }

public func getData(url: URL, parameters: [String: AnyObject]? = nil, completionHandler: @escaping ([Item], Error?) -> ()) {
    Alamofire.request(url, method: .get)
        .responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let val):
                let json = JSON(val)
                if let array = json.array {
                    var itemArray: [Item] = []
                    for item in array {
                        guard let dictionary = item.dictionaryObject else {
                            continue
                        }
                        itemArray.append(item)
                    }
                    completionHandler(itemArray, nil)
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
    }
}
```

This is a separated class, in which I do these operations, therefore this completionhandler. I have a simple `Item` class defined, which I would like to get an array of in my ViewController (using the array of objects to populate a table later). However, it does not seem to work like this?

```
var array = [Item]
let manager = APIManager()
APIManager.getItems(){ response in
    array = ...
}
```

This is how I have it in mind, but I'm not sure how this works exactly. Any thoughts? All help is appreciated.

Edit: originally, this used NSDictionary in the completionhandler, which is still in the code here. The idea is to just return an array of objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined your callback as `([Item], Error?) -> ()` so you should use it as:

```
var array = [Item]
let manager = APIManager()
APIManager.getItems() { items, error in
    array = items
    //and then you can reload tableview if it uses array as its source
}
```

Comment: I have been going through the code, and put this code above in my ViewController. It seems to go fine along the way, as there is data, but it does not put any data in the `array`? Stays empty

Comment: did you try to use breakpoints? maybe you have nothing from api

Comment: I did, even when printing the data where it is assigned to the `array`, it shows two items in there. Seems to go wrong when adding it to that one. I have my array declared like this: `var array = [Item]()`, when I remove the parentheses, it errors

Comment: when you have breakpoint in `array = items` in my code and print elements what happens?

Comment: It prints the correct items that should be in there. But when going out of the getItems() { items, error in .....} and print the array var, it is empty

Comment: where? are you trying to print it BEFORE it is filled with data from api?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156984/discussion-between-dnsko-and-lu).